# Shifting checkboxes with absolute position in bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have the following plnkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/hh2ItK6Jgcf0AC5PU9Tl?p=preview

```
.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
}

<div class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true">Industry</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" style="">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p class="selection">
          <label for="industry1">Industry 1</label>
          <span style="position: absolute; right: 30px;">
            <input class="category" id="industry1"
                   name="check" type="checkbox" value="industry-1" />
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to implement is an accordion dropdown that contains a list of options and checkboxes.

What is happening is that the checkbox moves as the accordion is expanding/collapsing. What I want is to have the checkbox not move during the expand/collapse phase so that it is always positioned 30px from the right.

What is the CSS magic to make that happen?

Comment: I don't have time to look further right now, but here are some notes. You are not clearing the floats inside of `.panel-title`. That is causing the main jump. Also, for some reason, it looks like the `.right` class causes about a 1px jump as well. Changing `.right` to `float: left` rather than `position: absolute` removes that 1px jump.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. I changed .right to be "float: right" (I assume you meant right, not left). But when I add `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` It will add a large bar below the `panel-title` but before the `panel-collapse`. I'll keep plugging away but let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, the main shift is due to the fact that the float inside the `.panel-title` is not being cleared.

I think my favorite solution would be to change `.panel-heading a:after` to `position: absolute`, and remove the float completely.

```
.panel-heading a:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f106";
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3593d0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 37.6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

You will want to add `position: relative` to its parent so that it is positioned absolutely within the parent element.

The `.right` class is causing a small jump as well. This can be helped in one of the following ways:

1 - Adding `position: relative` to the parent element, so that `.right` is absolutely positioned within that element, rather than some other element.

```
.selection {
    position: relative;
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
}
```

2 - Changing `.right` to `float: right` instead of `position: absolute`.

---

**Putting it all together:**

```
.selection {
    position: relative;
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
}

/* OR just .right { float: right; } */


/* -------- */

.panel-heading {
    position: relative;
}

.panel-heading a:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f106";
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3593d0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 37.6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
    content: "\f107";
}
```